# What is the difference between ("") and (null)

Tags: c#, winforms

While trying to set Validations i initially encountered some problems with checking if a textbox is null, i tried using

```
    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = textLogin.Text;
        if (name == null)
        {
             labelError.Visiblle = true;
             labelError.Text = "Field Cannot be Left Blank"
        }
    }
```

but it didn't work, until i tried this

```
    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = textLogin.Text;
        if (name == "")
        {
             labelError.Visiblle = true;
             labelError.Text = "Field Cannot be Left Blank"
        }
    }
```

My question is i want to know the difference between ("") and (null) and why null wasn't working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`string.IsNullOrEmpty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) is your friend, since it's so common to want to treat them the same for validation purposes.

Comment: "" means empty cup. null means nothing

Comment: the former is empty and the later is null isn't it ?
like, the emptiness itself does not exist. :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The same as the difference between `0` and an empty array: everything. They’re different values. `""` is an empty string, and that’s what a blank textbox holds as text is all. `null` is no value, and is not what a blank textbox has as `Text`.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. Sounds like you are saying that value from the empty text box should be saved in DB as '' (and NOT NULL). What if text box is visible but not editable for USER? (for example, they do not have permissions to modify particular attribute)? Do you recommend the same approach regardless of underlying DB? (for example, empty string and NULL are the same in Oracle and your application will not work correctly any longer)

Comment: @DrYWit: This is about `null` in C#, not in databases. Although I wouldn’t recommend treating SQL databases like they’re compatible anyway, or using Oracle at any point.

Comment: Thanks. I do not have any intention to turn this conversation into DB comparison but may I ask what capabilities are missing in Oracle which makes it not recommended DB for any scenario?

Comment: @DrYWit: It’s not missing capabilities, but the kind of weirdness that you just mentioned and the fact that it’s proprietary (and expensive).

Answer (score 6):

The `System.String` data type in .NET is a [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt.aspx), a reference type. So an empty string (`""` or `string.Empty`) is a reference to a value with zero length, while `null` does not reference a to real value, so any attempt to access the value it references will fail.

For example:

```
string emptyString = "";
string nullString = null;

Console.WriteLine(emptyString.Length); // 0
Console.WriteLine(nullString.Length);  // Exception!
```

I'd recommend you use [`IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) (or [`IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)) in your validation code, to handle both cases:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
     labelError.Visiblle = true;
     labelError.Text = "Field Cannot be Left Blank"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`""` is an empty string vs `null` which means "does not exist".

In your case, you first compared `name` to "does not exist" which was false because `name` did exist. Then you compared `name` to empty string which is true because it has the value of an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

The default value of `TextBox.Text` is `String.Empty` or `""` not null. So your first code didn't work. `null` is just to indicate that an object doesn't point to anything, it's not allocated with any memory.

Answer (score 2):

`null` simply means that the object (in this case, the `textLogin.Text` object) does not exist. In order for this to be the case, the textLogin object cannot exist. Thus the `textLogin` object is not null in this case, and thus `textLogin.Text` cannot be null.

`""` on the other hand means an empty string, meaning that there is nothing in the textbox's text. i.e. `textLogin.Text` does not contain any characters within it.

Answer (score 2):

In layman's term, `null` means lacking of value and `""` mean zero-length string, which is not the same thing. There might be some piece of software that treat `null` string and `""` equally e.g. `Console.WriteLine`, but it still does not make them the same thing.

Strictly speaking, `"" == null` expression is `false` by design. The equality comparison of `String` type in .NET framework works by [`==` operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx), which does not treat `null` as equal to `""`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to do text box input validation.  It checks for null, empty string or white space (tab, space, etc.).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Simple, `""` has a valid value i.e. `String.Empty` but `null` doesn't have any value.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `""` means and empty string but `null` means it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Null and Empty String i.e " " are not the same.
Null is an object reference value.
Null means no value while " " implies that there is a value, the value is an empty character.

An Object initialized to Null means that in memory this Object is not pointing to anything. It has got no worth or value. It's just declared. This doesn't mean it's value is "" or Zero.

While an Object initialized to " " means that in memory this Object is pointing to the byte code of " ". So this Object has a value.

In the context of a TextField, the TextField accepts characters, i.e letters, punctuations and numbers.
A TextField does operations on text not Null.

If you were to say

```
    String name = textLogin;
    if (name == null){
        }
```

( maybe you would need to cast textLogin to String, I'm not sure)

This would work because textLogin is an object. It would return the results that you want because this Object can have a null reference value.

But it would mean if you want the value of this textLogin, inside your "if" statement you would have to say,
name = textLogin.Text. This would give you a content inside the textLogin Object.

Since you chose to use

```
  String name = textLogin.Text;
  if (name == null){
        }
```

It's as if  textLogin.Text is already reference to an empty string should the TextField be empty. This is done under the hood for you so you don't have to deal with a NullPointExceptionError.

So "name" can never be null.
"name" can either be an empty string or a value.